# Why MongoDB compact command increases the size of the collection?

Tags: mongodb

I'm using MongoDB 4.2 with WiredTiger as storage engine. I'm testing the [compact collection command](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/compact/), so I get the storage size of the collection before running the command, then run compact command, finally check again storage size to see the saving in space:

```
> db.bikes.stats().storageSize
188416
> db.runCommand({compact:"bikes"})
{ "ok" : 1 }
> db.bikes.stats().storageSize
200704
```

Surprisingly, the collection has increased its storage size. I guess there would be a reason, but it is a bit counterintuitive. Documentation doesn't explain this situation (as much it says "The effectiveness of this operation is workload dependent and no disk space may be recovered" but it doesn't mention you can increse the space running compact).

Maybe I'm looking to a wrong metric in `stats()` or doing something wrong?